# Issue with # in URL with a Wordpress theme?

Tags: php, redirect, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am having a severe problem and have no clue about what is going on... I will specify the general issue which is causing multiple issues on this Wordpress powered portal.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Visit the URL: http://gamersgeographic.com/en/   (or any post on this site)
2. Append #abc  or #anything to the URL
3. The URL tries to resolve for a second and magically deletes the "#" and instead changes to /abc or /anything , which of course does not exist and gives a 404 page not found.
4. Even if the local anchor with #abc exists, behaviour is the same.

Now, consider the case below:

1. Visit http://gamersgeographic.com/monster-hunter-diary-1/
2. Comment link appends a #comments or #respond depending on whether a comment is there or not.
3. Both the anchors exist on the single post page
4. Still it redirects after finding them, to /comments and gives 404
5. Direct URL with #comments works e.g. http://gamersgeographic.com/monster-hunter-diary-1/#comments works but when I change any base URL to #comments, it redirects to 404...

I have tried several combinations with Permalinks, so it is not a problem with that. I even wrote my own Comment link generator in php with just a plain 
`href="#comments"`
but still no luck...

If you need any further information about any function's code in theloop.php or anything please let me know.

Thanks in advance !
Regards

The contents of .htaccess are as below:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: I want to stop this redirection. The link #comments exists and even works for a second, then redirects to /comments and hence gives 404... I want it to stay at URL/#comments and not change to URL/comments as you can see is happening...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a PHP issue, it is Javascript: it is evident when you reproduce it, and you can test it by disabling Javascript and adding `#comments` at the end of the URL; it will work.

Now, I have done some work for you, and the culprit is a Javascript file aptly named `hashchange.js`. Look, for example, at this line:

```
function second_passed() { 
    if(current_page!=location.href {
        get_page_by_hash(location.href);
    }
    setTimeout(second_passed,1000);
}
```

Which explains why you see it *“working”* for a second.

And here is the redirect:

```
jQuery(window).hashchange(function() {
    var link = window.location.hash.replace("#", "");
    get_page_by_hash(link)
});
```

Note that [`hashchange`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/hashchange/) is a method for event handling available in jQuery Mobile.

Comment: You are just plain brilliant... Thanks a million ! You rock... ^^

Comment: Glad to have been of help! ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="canonical" href="URL OF YOUR HOMEPAGE HERE>
```

add this in your header.php in `<head></head>` section and then try . it shouldn't be giving 404 error !

Comment: I added this:<link rel="canonical" href="http://gamersgeographic.com">   but nothing has changed. I want to stop this redirection. The link #comments exists and even works for a second, then redirects to /comments and hence gives 404... :(

Answer (score 0):

The way that page bookmarks are used is, as you know, the href="" of an anchor points to an #some-place.  In order for this to happen #some-place must be the id of the element within the page you wish to go to.

For example:

```
http://gamersgeographic.com/monster-hunter-diary-1/#respond
```

should take you to the element with id="respond" in that page.

If the element with that ID doesn't exist you won't be able to travel to it, and may be the reason it results in a 404 Not Found.  However, if the element does indeed exist on the page with the proper ID and it still redirects to a 404 then you may want to check your web server configuration to make sure it isn't filtering the # in some way.

Comment: @Nikhil If you're using Apache web server could you add/include the contents of your .htaccess file to your question?

Comment: It indeed works... That's the weirdest part. It only redirects when I change a URL to URL/#comments from the address bar or anchor... The element exists indeed... And the example link that you have given WORKS but try to load http://gamersgeographic.com/monster-hunter-diary-1/  and then add #comments in the address bar and press enter. Magically, it redirects to 404 at /comments...

Comment: .htaccess added but I don't think it is server config issue since the example URL you gave works on its own... It only happens when we change BASE_URL to BASE_URL/#something even via a link and then it redirects...

Comment: To make it clearer, http://gamersgeographic.com/en/#abc is fine...
But, http://gamersgeographic.com/en/ when changed to http://gamersgeographic.com/en/#abc  goes to http://gamersgeographic.com/en/abc and hence says 404...

Comment: Oddly enough when adding the #anchor to the URL the # is removed from the outgoing request.  If for example when you get to the 404 and hit the back button it goes right to where you would want it to.  Is there any JavaScript that might be having an effect on this?  I mean I don't see any reason other than a client-side issue at a glance.  Are you using an wordpress cache stuff, wordpress plugins?  Maybe try step removing different jquery plugins and stuff to see if that has an effect?